# how to externalize package in typescript application?

Tags: typescript, external, pixi.js

I am working on typescript project which has dependency on pixi.js. Till date we were using pixi by importing it as `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'` in required source files and downloaded it in node_modules folder and referring it through index.html's script tag as `<script scr="../node-modules/pixi/dist/pixi.min.js">`, also added as dependencies in package.json.
But we are now externalizing pixi by replacing local path by cdn path as `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.1.3/pixi.min.js" integrity="sha512-Ec75DRiwr6T4+Dpj4/CD12Cp+hs5zRpm6h/JVBLuViqbXdXfSU7gYS302B2w2abkwhUMxxHnLKDPdjvDpc+HmA==" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>` in index.html and added it in externals section in webpack.config.ts. Now the problem is that when I run my application it gives error as PIXI is undefined I have to remove import lines wherever I used `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'` to resolve this issue. I can not understand how my project is building successfully after removing import? even if at run time pixi.js is accessed through cdn path, for building my application declarations of pixi dependent classes will be required.
I checked if package for pixi is globally available on my system by it is not.
How to solve pixi undefined error without removing import and using it through cdn path?